# Conflicting jQuery scripts between expanding menu and expandable/collapsible list

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a redesign for a responsive website. I have run into a problem when I have to particular jQuery files linked in a page.

The first file is for the mobile menu at the top, basically shows three lines and when you click them it expands down to show the menu.

The second script is one I am using for a collapsible list.

The problem that arises is that when both are included the menu is always expanded, instead of expanding only when clicked. The collapsible list functions exactly how it should.

I have used both scripts on the same page in the past without issues, however that was using .asp pages instead of .html which I didn't think should matter?

Here is a copy of the first script for the menu:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined)
{
    'use strict';

    $(function ()
    {
        $("#mobileMenu").hide();
        $(".toggleMobile").click(function()
        {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $("#mobileMenu").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
    $(window).on("resize", function()
    {
        if($(this).width() > 500)
        {
            $("#mobileMenu").hide();
            $(".toggleMobile").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

And a script for the collapsible list:

```
$(function prepareList() {
$('#expList').find('li:has(ul)').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
    if(this == event.target) {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
    }
    return false;
}).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').children('ul').hide();

//Hack to add links inside the cv
$('#expList a').unbind('click').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'),'_self');
    return false;
});
//Create the button functionality
$('#expandList').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
    $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
})
$('#collapseList').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
    $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
})
});



//Functions to execute on loading the document

$(document).ready( function() {
prepareList()
});
```

I have messed around with it a bit to try to isolate the problem but all I was able to find is that if I take off the first line of the second script,

```
$(function prepareList()
```

the menu will go back to working correctly, but the collapsing list will of course stop.

If you have any ideas to try out I would appreciate it!

Comment: Don't you get a `ReferenceError: prepareList is not defined` when you use all the code you've posted?

Comment: @MartinErnst Thanks much! I hadn't considered that. I removed that bit of code at the end as that is what the reference error I found pointed to and it now works like a charm. I don't know why it worked with the same code on a previous site but I am very happy you pointed me to the solution.